# Create 2D modelling tool (as an UML modeller or BPM modeller) using C#.NET?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, 2d, modeling

I have to create a modelling tool (just as Visio, BizAgi or any graphical UML tool).
However I do *NOT* have any clue about *WHERE* to start.

I do know that it's going to be 2D modelling, always.
There will be relationships between the model entities just as a UML diagram or with a Visio Workflow.

I'm quite new into this...

How can this be performed using C#.NET?
Where should I start to digg for info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try using Windows Workflow foundation. It is not a very mature technology but it has some great features you may want to try.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx
By the way, we use bizagi here too. BizAgi Modeler it's free and complies with all the BPML specs.

Comment: Yeah, WF seems to be my best option. I've tried it a few times and it does provide me with something I need. This is a long-term project and for now we're just experimenting with some alternatives. BizAgi is just an example, since actual implementation would be about business rules inside my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [Diagram.Net](http://dalssoft.com/diagram/screenshots.aspx), it's Open Source

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the articles by Bob Powell, in particular this one:

[A Graphics Transform Stack](https://web.archive.org/web/20130331070932/http://www.bobpowell.net/graphicsstack.aspx)

He's written a whole load of tutorials on how to manipulate graphics in C#. Highly recommended.